# Testing ERC20 Token: Unable to cover Transfer and Approve from null/zero address

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm working on a project using Hardhat and OpenZeppelin library for an ERC20 token. I've been able to achieve almost 100% coverage, but there are two lines that I'm struggling to cover:

- `transfer` where the `from` is the zero/null address.
- `approve` where the `owner` is the zero/null address.

I haven't been able to find a way to "impersonate" the zero/null address in my tests to cover these scenarios and achieve 100% coverage. I've tried various approaches, but none of them seem to work. I know that these scenarios are super edge cases and may not be critical to test. However, I'm trying to achieve 100% test coverage. This issue has piqued my curiosity, and I'm eager to understand how to do it.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to cover:

Transfer

```js
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address"); // <--- This is the line I want to cover with a test
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");

        _beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
            // Overflow not possible: the sum of all balances is capped by totalSupply, and the sum is preserved by
            // decrementing then incrementing.
            _balances[to] += amount;
        }

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);

        _afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }
```

Approve

```js
function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(owner != address(0), "ERC20: approve from the zero address"); // <--- This is the line I want to cover with a test
        require(spender != address(0), "ERC20: approve to the zero address");

        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);
    }
```

This is an example of a test to cover transfer `to` the zero address

```js
    it('reverts when transfer to the zero address', async () => {
      const { contract } = await loadFixture(deployUSDMFixture);
      const { AddressZero } = ethers.constants;
      const amount = 1;

      await expect(contract.transfer(AddressZero, amount))
        .to.be.revertedWithCustomError(contract, 'ERC20InvalidReceiver')
        .withArgs(AddressZero);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to do it! The following test checks if an ERC20 token contract correctly rejects a transfer from the Zero address. It impersonates the zero address, funds it with Ether for paying the transfer transaction gas, and then attempts a token transfer, expecting a revert:

```js
it('reverts when transfer from the zero address', async () => {
  const { contract, owner } = await loadFixture(deployTokenFixture);
  const signerZero = await ethers.getImpersonatedSigner(AddressZero);

  // Fund the zero address to pay for the transaction
  await owner.sendTransaction({
    to: signerZero.address,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther('1') // Send 1 ETH
  });

  await expect(contract.connect(signerZero).transfer(signerZero.address, 1))
    .to.be.revertedWith('ERC20: transfer from the zero address');
});
```

Hope it's useful for you!